# Making Laravel Package. but "Class Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm making laravel's package.
But Class "Username/PackageName/Class" not found.

I read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages).
But I can't find problem.

Please help me.

This is my codes

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "username/packageName",
    "require": {
        "php": "7.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "username\\packageName\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "username\\packgeName\\TestServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

src/TestServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace username\packageName;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('test', function ($app) {
            return new Test();
        });
    }
}
```

src/Test.php

```
<?php
namespace username\packageName;

class Test {

    public static function test(){
        return 'abc';
    }

}
```

in Controller

```
use username\packageName\Test;

/* ~~~~ */

dd(Test::test()); // error
```

after add current composer.json.

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "vendor/username/packageName",
            "symlink": true
        }
    ]
```

```
> composer dump-autoload
```

Thank you for reading my codes.

---

username -> my username

packageName -> my package name

Comment: You also need to add the package to your project's `require` or `require-dev`. Adding the repository just tells Composer where to _find_ your package, not to actually include it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you `extend Facades` class in your Test Class.
If you want to fetch all function of your files statically,

```
class Test extends Facades {
 public static function getFacadeAccessor(){
   return 'classNameWhereFunctionIsWritten' //say TestService has test() function
 }
}
```

And Pass this `classNameWhereFunctionIsWritten` in your provider 'classNameWhereFunctionIsWritten' here.